# What is the correct ORDER BY syntax in DataJoint for Python?

Tags: python, database, open-source, datajoint

In DataJoint for Python, what is the correct syntax of the ORDER BY argument used in the `fetch` command?

The [current documentation](https://docs.datajoint.io/queries/Fetch.html) (as of 2018-08-17) only specifies the following syntax for DataJoint in MATLAB:

```
s = fetch(experiment.Session, '*', 'ORDER BY session_date DESC LIMIT 5')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, the correct syntax for the ORDER BY argument is

```py
table.fetch(order_by='attr')
```

If you need to sort by multiple attributes, provide them as a tuple:

```py
table.fetch(order_by=('attr1', 'attr2'))
```

This will sort the fetched items in ascending order with respect to the specified attributes. To make it descending, add the word `DESC` to the attributes.

```py
table.fetch(order_by='attr DESC')
table.fetch(order_by=('attr1 DESC', 'attr2'))
```

You may optionally also use the word `ASC` to make the ascending order implicit but omitting it has the same effect.